# How can I efficiently filter MagicCards.info searches down to cards castable with only certain mana colours?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I've been constructing a green/white commander deck, and doing a lot of searches on [MagicCards.info](http://magiccards.info/) for its cards. To cut out all the cards I can't use, I've been using the search term `c!gw` to get just green and white cards. But I just realised that's a terrible way to search — it filters out all the off-colour hybrid mana cards!

For example, a search of [`c!gw o:"enchant land" o:"mana pool"`](http://magiccards.info/query?q=c!gw+o%3A%22enchant+land%22+o%3A%22mana+pool%22&v=card&s=cname) yields a lot of green/white land ramping enchantments. But it excludes [Trace of Abundance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trace%20of%20Abundance), which costs {R/W}{G}, making it red and excluded from the search, despite being perfectly castable with just green and white mana and exactly the kind of card I want.

Using a more inclusive filter of `c:gw` would also include lots of three-colour cards which I cannot cast.

How can I filter a MagicCards.info search down to **only those cards I can cast with particular mana colours?** If my mana pool is *exclusively* green and white, is there a filter that will include cards I can cast with those colours, even if they're off-colour cards like [Figure of Destiny](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Figure%20of%20Destiny) and [Trace of Abundance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trace%20of%20Abundance)?

(Colourless cards can be included or left out. They are simple enough to search for separately with `c:c`, or exclude from the search with `-c:c`.)

(Also, it's been pointed out to me my group's been accidentally playing without the color identity rule. Doesn't matter! Still good. Question ahoy!)

Comment: But a card with {R/W} would be illegal in a GW commander deck, wouldn't it? E.g. http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Commander_(format)#Deckbuilding_Rules  (although it's a casual format and your playgroup may have a different opinion)

Comment: @RemcoGerlich D'oh, right you are. I think we've been playing without that colour identity rule, just with the "whatever you can cast" thing. Only affects a few of our cards, but thanks.

Comment: This is a beautiful example of how to ask for a process instead of a list of cards. Nice work!

Comment: @Rainbolt I appreciate the sentiments about this being a good process example, but I wouldn't dream of asking for a card list for something like this anyway. I asked for a process 'cause it was what I needed, no more or less.

Comment: `c!wg` used to mean "castable using only white and green", so `c!wg "Trace of Abundance"` used to return Trace of Abundance. It appears this has been broken. :( Maybe when Commander became popular before `ci:wg` was introduced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is effectively equivalent to "the mana cost does not contain {U}, {B}, {R}, {U/B}, {U/R}, or {B/R}" because those are all of the mana symbols that *cannot* be paid from your mana pool. This can be equivalently expressed by negating the expression that says "the mana cost contains any one of those symbols". So, the resulting query is

> [**-(mana>=u or mana>=b or mana>=r or mana>={U/B} or mana>={U/R} or mana>={B/R})** o:"enchant land" o:"mana pool"](http://magiccards.info/query?q=-%28mana%3E%3Du%20or%20mana%3E%3Dr%20or%20mana%3E%3Db%20or%20mana%3E%3D%7BU%2FB%7D%20or%20mana%3E%3D%7BU%2FR%7D%20or%20mana%3E%3D%7BB%2FR%7D%29%20o%3A%22enchant%20land%22%20o%3A%22mana%20pool%22&v=card&s=cname)

Note the `-` at the beginning that negates the bolded expression. As you can see, this does in fact list every card your search found, plus Trace of Abundance. It also incidentally includes colorless cards and cards with Phyrexian and colorless hybrid mana symbols (e.g. {UP} or {2/R}) because it is possible to play those without spending any mana of their colors at all.

Comment: Hooray! I didn't realise I could bend the mana term quite so conveniently. This seems to also include Phyrexian mana (e.g. [this search](http://magiccards.info/query?q=-%28mana%3E%3Du+or+mana%3E%3Dr+or+mana%3E%3Db+or+mana%3E%3D{U%2FB}+or+mana%3E%3D{U%2FR}+or+mana%3E%3D{B%2FR}%29+o%3Acounter+mana%3E%3D{UP}&v=card&s=cname)), but I'm going to consider that a bonus feature (especially since this is going into a lifegain deck, but handy even without that).

Comment: That was on purpose. By using an exclusion-based search, you can find *any* card that is castable with only {W} and {G} in your mana pool. I added a note to make that explicit. I just realized that there are some cards that arguably should be in the list, but it's unlikely that you'd want to play Force of Will or Mindbreak Trap if it is impossible to hard-cast them.

Answer (score 2):

[Trace of Abundance](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Trace%20of%20Abundance) is not allowed in White-Green Commander deck.

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

> 903.5c A card can be included in a Commander deck only if every color in its color identity is also found in the color identity of the deck’s commander.

Trace of Abundance's color identity is White, Red and Green. It can't be included in a deck whose Commander's color identity is White and Green.

You should be using magiccards.info's `ci` filter. It allows you to limit the results to those matching a color identity. For a White-Green Commander, you'd specify `ci:wg`. Of course, this is even more restrictive than `c!wg`, so Trace of Abundance will not be returned by a query with that filter.

---

If you were constructing a non-Commander deck and you wanted to search for "cards castable using only White and Green", I'm pretty sure you were once able to use `(c!wg or c:c)`. This means that `(c!wg or c:c) "Trace of Abundance"` used to return Trace of Abundance.

Unfortunately, it appears this is no longer the case, so you'll need to exclude the mana symbols you can't use instead: `-(mana>=u or mana>=b or mana>=r or mana>={U/B} or mana>={U/R} or mana>={B/R})`.

Comment: I've accepted the other answer as a solution to what I was looking for (this'll be relevant for non-commander decks I make too), but the colour identity was something else I didn't know was available and is certainly helpful. I have the feeling this should still be recorded in another question about MagicCards.info, and I'd like the portion of your answer about colour identity to also be posted there. Is this OK with you, and do you want to have some input on how that question is formed?

Comment: It's fine. You can even go ahead and answer it yourself. No need for credit or anything.